# Get the last inserted item using Document Model or Object Persistence Model using .Net core with DynamoDB

Tags: .net-core, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I am able to get the last inserted item using low level API as showed in code below using .net core

But is it possible to get the last inserted item using high level API such as **Document Model** or **Object Persistence Model**?

Prefer **Object Persistence Model** if possible.  I am not able to find a way to do it, also, I would like DynamoDB to query and return the last item only.  I understand that I can get a list of items inserted and get the last item myself in memory, but it is not preferable since it require a lot more read and data transfer.

Thanks

```
public async Task<DailyStockRecordDao> GetTheLastInsertedItem(string tickerSymbol)
{
    QueryRequest request = getTheLastItemRequest(tickerSymbol);

    var response = await _dynamoDBClient.QueryAsync(request);

    return null;

}

private static QueryRequest getTheLastItemRequest(string tickerSymbol)
{
    string partitionName = ":v_PartitionKeyName";
    var request = new QueryRequest
    {
        TableName = Constants.TableName,
        KeyConditionExpression = $"{Constants.PartitionKeyName} = {partitionName}",
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
            { $"{partitionName}", new AttributeValue {
                S = tickerSymbol
            } }
        },
        // Optional parameter.
        ConsistentRead = false,
        Limit = 1,
        ExclusiveStartKey = null,
        ScanIndexForward = false
    };
    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the below data-structure to achieve this.

```
pk    value
----------------------------------------------
key1  value1
key2  value2
key3  value3
latest {key: key1, value:value1}
```

While doing write, do 2 writes instead of 1. and while reading just do a get using pk=latest.

Comment: it will work, but then it will require using Transaction to do the two writes, and currently only low level APIs are available for Transaction using .net.  So, it will make the code a lot more complicated then necessary.

Comment: instead of using transaction, you can do key value write and have an aws lambda function(keep concurrency=1 for serializability) updating latest. it will mean introducing a new component in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add one more column called `created_counter`, and insert the value starting with numeric 1, then 2, then 3 and so on?
Make the `created_counter` as `sort key`.
To reverse the order, set the `ScanIndexForward` parameter to false.

Use limit 1, to get the last inserted data.